# getting error on trying to access record in listener of live query

Tags: orientdb

I have created listener as described in [live query](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-docs/blob/master/Live-Query.md#livequery-in-java) document

i get a callback when i do some operations on the class using orient studio, but i am getting below error when i try to access the record

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Database instance is not set in current thread. Assure to set it with: ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.set(db);
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.get(ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.java:51)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordAbstract.getDatabase(ORecordAbstract.java:240)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.getGlobalPropertyById(ODocument.java:2155)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocumentInternal.getGlobalPropertyById(ODocumentInternal.java:60)
```

and i am setting database instance to ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.instance.set(db)